# Solr to SolrCloud migration

Tags: solr

We are trying to migrate the existing Solr standalone server to SolrCloud. Have tested the SolrCloud setup in testing account and curious to know how to migrate the indexed data from Solr standalone to SolrCloud.

Current Solr standalone version: 7.7.1

Planning to migrate SolrCloud version: 8.11.1

Looking for your help guys.

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: It’s generally a good idea to start with empty collections and let Sitecore update those collections with content from the database. Are you able to rebuild your indexes from Sitecore?